# treeview error in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have three `Buttons`, one `TextBox` and a `TreeView`. I am adding nodes dynamically to the `TreeView`. I used some code and it is working for the first(root) button. It shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error for other two buttons. My three buttons are: `Add root`, `Add child`, `Delete`.

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode t;
    t = treeView1.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode t;
    t = treeView1.SelectedNode;
    t.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);
    treeView1.SelectedNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}
```

Comment: You should create a new question for the new problem since this one is marked answered already. It will help others in the future when they search for this error to find an answer related to the title/original question.

Comment: k thanks for ue nice suggestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [treeview error in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288549/treeview-error-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown when you access `treeView1.SelectedNode` when there is no selected item at that moment.

The fix could be:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible issue is, you iddnt select the newly added/existing item in treeview node before deleting/adding child nodes on that.

You check what is t before performing adding child.

First time its working because, root is selected, next time not working because the new item added is not selected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is proably you didnt select anything, you can tell user to select or you can manually select.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
   else
      Messagebox.Show ("Please select the node first");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode t;
        t = treeView1.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);
        treeView1.SelectedNode = t;

    }
```